# How does passing data around different views/pages work on angularJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I am learning angularJS, went through few tutorials and sort of know my why around. It seems that the page never refreshes, therefore a value created in one view should be available in another view, right? I am testing this in a shop scenario. If we are at the main view, and we click on "add to cart" that should trigger a function in the background and add the item in an array. Then when we go to the cart view, we can see the item listed there. But this does not work.

I have a cart controller:

```
angular.module('shoppingCartApp')
  .controller('CartCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.cart = [
    'one item'
    ];
    $scope.pushing = function(item){
        this.cart.push(item);
    };
  });
```

In the main view (which doesn't have access to this controller) I have.

```
<div  ng-controller="CartCtrl">
<a href="" ng-click="pushing('item 2')">add to chart</a>
</div>
```

And on the cart view I display the `cart` object

```
<div ng-repeat="item in cart">
    {{item}}
</div>
```

We only see the `one item`. I have also added the `ng-click` attribute to this page as well, just to test, and it does work, however, if we go home and come back, the item is gone.

From the idea that the page never reloads, should the pushed items stay in the array? here is the simple [example in action](http://embed.plnkr.co/PSvHmS2iS6rO0K1NZryS/preview)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Controllers` are not singletons, so when you change the view the `$scope` gets destroyed and a new `controller` will be initialized. If you want persistent data across different views then you want to look at using a `service` to store it, since they are singletons.

If you create something like

```
angular.module('app')
.service('cartService', [function() {
    var cart = [];
    var add = function(item) {
      cart.push(item);
    };
    var get = function() {
      return cart;
    };
    return {
      add: add,
      get: get
    };       
}]);
```

Then you can add that as a dependency in your `controllers` and use that for backing your data rather than using the `$scope`.

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('Ctrl', ['cartService', function(cartService) {
    $scope.cart = cartService.get();

    $scope.pushing = function(item) {
      cartService.add(item);
    };
}]);
```